# Clear all the contet in class elements using getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

Im trying to make all my div class elements to lose all its content by replacing their current content with nothing "".

```
document.getElementsByClassName("sprint_column").innerHTML = "";
```

But nothing happens with the "sprint_column" when im trying to reach the class, However if i try to reach the IDs it works:

```
document.getElementsById("div3_Score").innerHTML = "";
```

Here is the code where the Ids and Classes is created:

```
<div class='sprint_column' id='div3_".$team."'>Sprint 1</div>
```

Is there any way to clear all content from a class with "getElementsByClassName" or do i have to loop through all ID elements and clear them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of DOM elements. You need to iterate through them, e.g. via a `for` loop, and change the `innerHTML` one by one.

Comment: It returns an HTML collection, not an array.